# When one begins debugging a program, is the program swapped out of main memory (into secondary memory)?

Tags: debugging, memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

My textbook makes the following claim:

> If a user suspects a bug in the program, he or she may debug the program by suspending its execution, examining, and modifying the program or data, and resuming execution.

In this context, suspend means to swap out of main memory and into secondary memory.

For instance, when I debug a C/Python/Java program, is the program swapped out of main memory at that time? Or am I misunderstanding what the author is saying?

Comment: When you debug a C program, it is still being executed in CPU just step by step where you can see what is happening, hence it's in `main memory`.

Comment: @TonyTannous Thanks for the response. So the textbook's claim is incorrect?

Comment: What I think they meant was that you should debug it with your eyes. Open it in a text editor and start checking your program. Not in a debugger.
Perhaps I'm wrong though... wait for more responses.

Comment: @TonyTannous Ok. Thanks for the assistance. :)

Comment: *"suspend means to swap out of main memory and into secondary memory"* -- That's not a conventional definition for "suspend".  A process can be suspended, and still be memory resident.

Comment: @sawdust That's illuminating. Thank you for the clarification. In response to  TonyTannous's previous comment, does that mean that a program is still necessarily being executed by the processor during debugging?

Comment: Depends on how the program is being "debugged", e.g. in-circuit emulator or software debugger, and if breakpoints are employed.

Comment: @sawdust What if we assume a software debugger?

Comment: A software debugger could selectively execute or single step a program.  When a breakpoint is encountered, the target program would transfer control to the debugger.  The target program is not suspended in the same sense as an OS scheduler.  Seems like you're asking XY questions, and the root issue is what is process suspension and when is a process swapped out, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging DOES NOT involve swapping out the program. The "suspend" in debugging usually is caused by forcing an BREAKPOINT instruction into the stream. This triggers the operating system's BREAKPOINT FAULT handler. The actual connection between the debugger and the application depends upon the operating system.

If the program got swapped to secondary storage there would be no way to examine its memory usage.